# perforce p4 with the -x option performance

Tags: synchronization, perforce

I was using the `p4 -x file.txt` option to sync a lot of files.
And I noticed that the performance suffered.

the files inside file.txt has like around 500k lines.

and i compared between these 2 commands:-

```
p4 -x file.txt sync
p4 sync ...
```

From what i noticed, the `-x` seems to be much slower, but i'm not really sure if that is really the case, or it is just my network/other stuff which causes the discrepancy.

Would appreciate if someone could share

- some insight in this regarding the `-x` option's performance
- and if it is true that it is slower, is there an alternative to make it faster?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the two is that with `-x`, the file arguments are being passed individually.  It's exactly equivalent to if you ran `p4 sync file1 file2 file3 ... file500000` at the command line.  (Note: technically they're further broken into batches, of about 200 IIRC, so it's really more like running 2500 separate sync commands with 200 arguments each.)

If you add the `-Ztrack` global option to the command, you get a lot of performance tracking output that helps to explain this, but the short of it is that with `p4 sync ...` the server is able to do a very efficient batched read from the database to fetch all of the files in a way that takes advantage of data locality.  In terms of disk access, it's able to do a single seek and then a bunch of large sequential reads.  With a command like `p4 sync file1 file2 file3 ... file500000`, each file is handled one at a time, as a single seek and a read of a single record, which makes the disk access pattern slower (there's still data locality, but the database is no longer able to optimize the reads to the same extent).

With the multi-argument syntax, access checks also need to be applied to each file individually, whereas with a wildcard pattern the server is able to check the entire pattern at once to determine if you have access to all of the files under that path.  (This is less of an issue with respect to I/O but might add a bit of compute time.)

The short of it is that to the extent you can express things as simple patterns, that will always be faster than enumerating individual files.  Take a step back from the XY problem of how to sync all the file paths in that local file -- how did that path list get generated in the first place?  It might be possible to just cut the file out of the equation directly -- maybe it should be a label instead of a local file?  Maybe it could even be an "automatic" label?

Comment: as usual, thanks a lot for the very insightful reply. All your replies in perforce is very helpful ! Thank you